VBA String variable limitation for PowerShell output of File list in a folder
I am trying to export file properties of all files in a Root Folder and Subfolders. This is a huge file DB with around 300000 files. I have been using PowerShell for this purpose but the string variable is limiting my output.
Sub SO()

Const parentFolder As String = "\\eugbp-anas0001\hr_xythos_prd\SharedFolder\UK\" '// change as required, keep trailing slash
Dim results As String

    results = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll
    'Range("A1").Value = results

Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\rkchal\Desktop\Export\OUTPUT.txt")
    oFile.WriteLine results
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub

How can I overcome this limitation and get a Text file with complete list?
Thanks in advance.

What part of this question involves powershell?

You can pipe the output directly to a file:
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec _
   "CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D > C:\Tester\output.txt"

...or to the clipboard:
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec _
   "CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D | clip"

